# Dependency injection and Inheritance in Java

Tags: java, dependencies, code-injection, reusability

I have the following code:

```
public class GrandParent {    
    public void greet() {
        System.out.println("Hello from grandpa.");
    }    
}

public class Parent extends GrandParent {    
    public void run() {
        greet();
    }                   
}

public class RunMe {       
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Parent p = new Parent();
        p.run();
    }

    public void greet() {
        System.out.println("Hi.");
    }    
}
```

I am tasked to write the class RunMe and as much as possible, I am not allowed to modify classes Parent and GrandParent. How can I implement this in such a way that when execution reaches run() of Parent, the greet() of RunMe (or it could be in another place) is executed and not the greet() of GrandParent.

Or is this possible in the first place?

Comment: How does dependency injection fit here?

Comment: Are you not allowed at all to modify the classes or "as much as possible" don't modify them?  Can you edit your question to make it more clear?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this is possible if you are to have a non-extended Parent object call a different greet method without changing Parent or Grandparent code.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an instance (not static) inner class within RunMe that extends Parent and overrides Parent instance's run() such that it makes a call to the RunMe instance's run(). Your main() method would create an instance of the new subclass instead of Parent.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need an instance of `RunMe` to invoke its `run()` method, since that isn't a static method. One way to hook into what's happening in `Parent` is to subclass `Parent`:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    final RunMe runMe = new RunMe();
    Parent p = new Parent() {
        public void run() {
            super.run(); // runs Parent.run()
            runMe.run(); // runs the hook function
        }
    };
    p.run();
}
```

I have no idea if this is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class MyParent extends Parent {    
    @Override
    public void greet() {
        System.out.println("hello from MyParent");
    }                   
}

public class RunMe {       
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Parent p = new MyParent();
        p.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant this:

```
public class RunMe extends Parent {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Parent p = new RunMe();
        p.run();
    }

    public void greet() {
        System.out.println("Hi.");
    }
}
```